# OData Client Code Generator- ByKey method is not defined

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I am working with **OData Client Code Generator v4** and **WebApi 2**
I have **One-To-Many** Relationship between two tables(**Teacher** and **Subject**) and I am trying to get **Subjects of Teacher**.

My scenario is same as described in the following blog post(where we can access the Parent of Boss):
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/07/09/odata-client-code-generator-2-0-0-release.aspx.

But the problem is that when I code, Visual studio gives an error that **ByKey** 
method is not defined.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you checked whether the ByKey function exists in the generated code ? It should be in ExtensionMethods class.

Comment: Hi, @LaylaLiuMSFT
Yes the function exists in the class that is generated by OData Client Code Generator.

Comment: @Sameet, Could you please provide me your service metadata? and the generated code piece?